# Finding similar code sections using sub-trees

Tags: algorithm, parsing, language-agnostic, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree

I have been reading this paper titled [Clone Detection using Abstract Syntax Trees](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.70.1272&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Ira D. Baxter et al. There is a paragraph from the paper that I reproduced below:

> In principle, finding sub-tree clones
>   is easy: compare every subtree to
>   every other sub-tree for equality. In
>   practice, several problems arise:
>   near-miss clone detection, sub-clones
>   and scale. 
>   ...
>
> When locating near-miss
>   clones, hashing on complete subtrees
>   fails precisely because good hashing
>   functions include all elements of the
>   tree, and thus sorts tress with minor
>   differences into different buckets. We
>   solved this problem by choosing an
>   **artificially bad hash function**. This function must be characterized in
>   such a way that the main properties
>   one wants to find on near-miss clones
>   are preserved. Near miss clones are
>   usually created by copy and paste
>   procedures followed by small
>   modifications. These modifications
>   usually generate small changes to the
>   shape of the tree associated with the
>   copied piece of code. Therefore, we
>   argue that this kind of near-miss
>   clone often have only some different
>   small sub-trees. Based on this
>   observation, a hash function that
>   ignores small sub-trees is a
>   goodchoice. **In the experiment
>   presented here, we used a hash
>   function that ignores only the
>   identifier names (leaves in the tree).
>   Thus our hashing function puts trees
>   which are similar modulo identifiers
>   into the same hash bins for
>   comparison.**

I am trying to implement the techniques discussed in this paper but am stuck in trying to understand this one paragraph (that is unfortunately at the beginning of the paper). I understand what the paragraph is saying but the authors do not mention what hash function to choose or how to actually hash the ASTs. Can someone please explain this with a simple example from an implementation standpoint?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shades that the author himself should answer.  Isn't StackOverflow great :-?

The point of hash functions is that which one you choose doesn't matter, as long as it distributes input values evenly across a large number of buckets.   You need a hash function that can be applied to the entire tree; the usual technique for such is to serialize the tree in any way possible (say, by an in-order tree visit) and then apply the hash function to the stream of values (tree nodes) this produces. (This idea is from the compiler literature on detecting common subexpressions, which was the inspiration for the original CloneDR).   If this isn't clear, you need to spend more energy understanding how hash functions are applied to complex data structures.  Wikipedia on [hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) is a good place to start; if that's not enough, you need to find a book on algorithms and study up.

What you feed to the hash function is up to you.  The point I made in the paper is that you can compute hash functions that ignore the identifier leaves of an AST, which will cause trees having the same identical structure but different identifiers to hash to the same bucket.  Thus, trees which are similar modulo identifiers are easily matched, beause they occur in the same hash bucket.

Of course, there's a lot more to the whole clone detection algorithm that just matching trees modulo identifiers.  You need to worry about matching parameterized *sequences* (which is sort of the big point in the paper), reporting the results, and of course you need a high-quality language parser for whatever language you care to apply this to.

You can see results of the [CloneDR](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Clone) for a number of different languages.

Comment: Either the SO search engine is extremely good or I am extremely lucky to get a reply from the author. Either ways it is a win-win for me :) Your explanation clarifies my question. As a final request, would you recommend any follow-up works to your paper after I finish reading it? (Any state-of-the-art work in this area that you feel I should be familiar with before putting on the developer hat). By the way, a really great paper!

Comment: @Legend: A good index of the clone detection literation can be found at http://students.cis.uab.edu/tairasr/clones/literature/  Rather a lot has been written since my paper was published.  Most of the argument is a) how do you detect clones, and b) how do you make it scale well.   Elmar Juergen's papers are good on scaling, but he scales well by giving up parameterization.  I'm pleased to say there are other tree-detection papers, but pretty much CloneDR has really stood the test of time.  The commercial version doesn't quite work like the paper but details won't be published.

Comment: @Legend: If you want to hear state of the art, you need to attend the Software Clones workshop at the International Conference on Software Engineering in Hawaii in May. Besides, its a great boondoggle of a trip :-} See you there!

Answer (score 2):

If you know that two ASTs are "clones" to your human eye you want to make sure they have the same hash value also.

For example, hash every identifier to a constant and every string to another constant to avoid getting tricked by variable renaming, instead of actually using identifier name as material part of hashing.

Or use commutative hashing for expression that are commutative, I.e. make sure a+b and b+a get the same hash value.

Example for arithmetic expressions involving variables, integers, operators and parenthesis:

```
 hash VariableName = 0x12345678
 hash IntegerConstant = 0xff77ff77
 hash x + y = (hash x) + (hash y)
 hash (x) = (hash x) <<< 13
 hash x * y = (hash x) xor (hash y)
```

Etc.